# Heroku run node

Tags: node.js, heroku

whenever I try to run node with Heroku it displays a garbage prompt. This is in Windows command prompt.
[image]

Has anyone else had this problem and figured out how to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like you might have an issue with UTF-8 unicode on your terminal.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to check that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows terminals, sorry :( This does look like an UTF-8 issue though. Do you know how to check your terminal encoding? It should ideally be set to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Some Windows users have had success working around Windows' garbling of ANSI escape codes like this:

```
heroku config:set NODE_NO_READLINE=1
heroku run node
```